# Почему НН?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово перочинный пишется с двумя НН?

Answer (score 2):

если разобрать по составу, то получим: пер-о-чин-н-ый.
Первое Н - от корня (чинить), второе Н - суффикс.

Comment: А разве это правило относится не только к прилагательным, образованным от существительных?

Comment: Простите, какое правило?
Вы об этом?

у прилагательных, образованных от существительных с основой на н (вторая н - суффикс прилагательного): длинный (длин-а), истинный (истин-а), миллионный (миллион), старинный (старин-а), холстинный (холстин-а), ценный (цен-а), фельетонный (фельетон);

http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.25

Ну так это тут говорится о только существительных, а запрета на образования с помощью суффикса от других частей речи нет. 
Совсем без суффикса тут же никак не получится, нет аналогов. Ко всему прочему "чин" это тоже существительное. Напрямую от чинить было бы "?перочиненный".

Comment: *Перочиненный* - обработанный перочинным ножом, так? Страд. причастие как бы. *Перочинный* нож - тот, который *чинит* (очиняет) перья и карандаши. Чванный - тот, кто чванится.  
Без суффиксов : юный, румяный.

Comment: Интересно, а единый почему с одной?

Comment: Единый = один

Comment: >Интересно, а единый почему с одной?   
  
А хороший вопрос, однако. Навскидку есть такое объяснение.  
Один (един) - по своим грамматическим свойствам самом по себе  является кратким прилагательным для единый. Чтобы в этом убедиться, достаточно просклонять "один" - и обратить внимание на падежные окончания.  Понятно, сто для образования полных прилагательных от кратких (исторически краткие возникли раньше) никаких дополнительных сцффиксов не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Перочинный - предназначенный для того, чтобы делать острыми перья (чинить их, точить), которыми писали в стародавние времена

Comment: Спасибо, Кэп! (С)

Answer (score 0):

Чеканить – чеканный, бранить – бранный, чваниться – чванный, жеманиться – жеманный.  В данной группе отглагольных прилагательных с двумя буквами НН удвоение НН происходит на стыке морфем, как и для отыменных прилагательных. Суффикс Н имеет значение признака или свойства, отнесенного к действию. Перочинный - сложное прилагательное, способ образования - суффиксальное сложение, его можно отнести к той же группе.